# Css in Android/ iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, html, css

I need help with a page in html 5 for android and iphone.
It should contain two links that are 5% on the bottom of the screen. I tried using CSS by placing a table or div with absolute position and bottom 5%. But the virtual keyboard this `decoupled` links above the virtual keyboard when it appears and disappears when the site returns.
I tried not to use absolute position and place within the footer tag, and presents the same problem.
If it was a native android project could use: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing", but I can not use it because it is a web project.
I have many items up these links that should get the screen below:

---

margin-top: 20%
img logo (80% width of screen)

margin-top: 10%
input login

margin-top: 10%
input pass

margin-top: 10%
button

margin-top: 5%
other link

blank area

area links botton in the page (botton and 5% of botton)

---

The logo image should have a width of 80% and let its height be set automatically to not distort.
And all this must be equal for all iphone and android devices (tablets and smartphones)
Help!

Comment: @morpheus, seriously? Thats your advice?

Answer (score 0):

You might try: `<img src="image.jpg" width="80%">`. If you only specify the width, the height should be automatically set proportionally. That's the way it works in browsers, but i'm not sure how it will behave inside a phone app.

Comment: @ morpheus kkk, yes this is the app for my company. It was past the specification and have to answer it.
riverstorm I use the code for the image of the company logo, but my problem is in letting in any type of mobile device the 5% two links at the bottom of the screen and the virtual keyboard does not "push" them up when appear ...